# Ctrlp.vim open a file in current pane

Tags: vim

I've started using CtrlP.vim and love it. I'd like know if it is possible to make it open files in the currently active pane, as illustrated in my screenshot.

[image: This is what I'd like to do]

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm, did you try `<Enter>`?

Comment: @Mokubai, this *is* the answer to the question (hitting `<Enter>` is the default mapping for opening the selected file/buffer in the current window) *and* also a critique.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I was unaware of this and it seemed as it it were a comment. I would suggest adding your information into your answer to clarify it. I will delete my comment.